# Self contained html with quarto and plots

Tags: r, quarto, self-contained

I want to create a self-contained html from a quarto (rmarkdown) notebook. Whenever I include plots, the notebook stops being self-contained. I feel like I am missing one option but I cant find it. In addition to the option "self-contained" I also tried "embed-resources" with same results.

I am using R version 4.1.2, VSCode and quarto version 1.2.335.

Here is the example, thanks (sorry the stackoverflow tags are messing with the quarto code tags). When I render it, I get the file ,test.html’ and the folder ‘test_files’ instead of just one html file.

````
---
title: "Test"
format:
  html:
    self-contained: true
---

```{r}
x <- y <- 1:10
```

```{r}
plot(x, y)
```
````

Comment: Can you explain why it is not self contained? Because your example works fine for me. It produces the plot in the html file: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVB...`

Comment: I edited and explained

Comment: I have compiled exactly the mentioned code with R 4.1.2 in R-Studio 2022.12.0  (unix) and it works as intended... So the issue may be somewhere else.